# Стоит ли переходить на новые версиси NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Дело в том, что на оф. сайте NodeJs есть 2 версии: новейшая и рекомендуемая. У меня вопрос, стоит ли устанавливать новейшую или подождать пока она станет рекомендуемой?

Надеюсь понятно, что я имею ввиду.

Comment: В "новейшей" dev-версии могут быть новые фичи и, самое главное, новые баги. Когда баги фиксят, версия становится рекомендуемой и начинается разработка новой. И без веских причин смысла рисковать нет! Только если новые фичи крайне необходимы, либо желаете помочь разработчикам найти эти самые баги.

Comment: При переходе на новую версию также стоит убедиться, что все части проекта имеют поддержку новой версии NodeJs.